# index.tsx:24 Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using use location to hide the navbar if the pathname name is `/admin`, `/employee`, `/publisher`. but I got an error saying that `Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
This is My `App.js`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';


function App() {
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    <>
      
      <UserState>
      <Router>
      {!["/admin", "/employee", "/publisher"].includes(location.pathname) && <Navbar/>}  //For to hide the navbar if the pathname is /admin, /employee, /publisher
        <Routes onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>

          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/service" element={<Service />} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/reset" element={<Reset />} />
          <Route exact path="/reset/:token" element={<Newpassword />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoteFound/>} />

          {/* admin pages */}
          <Route  path="/admin" element={<Admin />}>
          <Route   path="add-project" element={<Addproject />} />
          <Route   path="all-user" element={<AllUser />} />
          </Route>

          {/* Publisher dasboard */}
          <Route  path="/publisher" element={<Publisher />}>
          <Route   path="project-status" element={<ProjectStatus />} />
          <Route  path="allpublise" element={<Allpublise />} />
          </Route>
          
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </UserState>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useLocation` hook (*and all other `react-router-dom` hooks*) need a router ***above*** it in the ReactTree so that a routing context is available.

2 options:

1. Move the `Router` component up the tree and wrap the `App` component so it can use the `useLocation` hook.

   ```
   import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   <Router>
     <App />
   </Router>
   ```

   ...

   ```
   import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
   import Navbar from './components/Navbar';


   function App() {
     const location = useLocation();

     return (
       <UserState>
         {!["/admin", "/employee", "/publisher"].includes(location.pathname) && <Navbar/>}
         <Routes onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
           <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
           <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
           <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
           <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset />} />
           <Route path="/reset/:token" element={<Newpassword />} />
           <Route path="*" element={<NoteFound/>} />

           {/* admin pages */}
           <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />}>
             <Route path="add-project" element={<Addproject />} />
             <Route path="all-user" element={<AllUser />} />
           </Route>

           {/* Publisher dasboard */}
           <Route path="/publisher" element={<Publisher />}>
             <Route path="project-status" element={<ProjectStatus />} />
             <Route path="allpublise" element={<Allpublise />} />
           </Route>
         </Routes>
       </UserState>
     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```
2. Move the `useLocation` hook down the tree so that it's used within the `Router` component.

   ```
   import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
   import Navbar from './components/Navbar';


   function App() {
     return (
       <UserState>
         <Router>
           <Navbar/>
           <Routes onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
             <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
             <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
             <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
             <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
             <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset />} />
             <Route path="/reset/:token" element={<Newpassword />} />
             <Route path="*" element={<NoteFound/>} />

             {/* admin pages */}
             <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />}>
               <Route path="add-project" element={<Addproject />} />
               <Route path="all-user" element={<AllUser />} />
             </Route>

             {/* Publisher dasboard */}
             <Route path="/publisher" element={<Publisher />}>
               <Route path="project-status" element={<ProjectStatus />} />
               <Route path="allpublise" element={<Allpublise />} />
             </Route>
           </Routes>
         </Router>
       </UserState>
     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const Navbar = () => {
     const location = useLocation();

     return !["/admin", "/employee", "/publisher"].includes(location.pathname)
       ? /* Return navbar JSX here */ 
       : null;
   };
   ```

Comment: hey, @DrewReese Thanks a lot! it works I Just wrap `<App> using <Router>` inside the `index.js`. and Write the navbar above the `<Route> start tag`. thanks again

Comment: I was having the same issue. The bit I was missing was to add <Router><Router/> part into index.js and not in the App.js (you can't have it in both), which then fixed the ```"useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component"``` that I was getting regardless of what I did with App.js

Answer (score 1):

`useLocation()` hook is used to extract the current location from the router.
For this purpose it's need the router context to pass the Location content

So if you want to use this hook, you need to use it in one of the nested components in `<Router>` Provider.

For your situation, you need to move the hook into the navbar component.

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';



function Navbar() {
  const location = useLocation()
  if(["/admin", "/employee", "/publisher"].includes(location.pathname)) 
      return <></> 
  return (
    <>
     I'm a navbar
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```